# Class with custom Constraint

Tags: c#, matrix, constraints, operators

How can I do this? Limit to use defined operation Data Types(T) or
limit to use an T whit Defined for all addition, multiplication and subtraction operations here is my Matrix class

```
class Matrix<T> where T :  /*Defined for all addition, multiplication and subtraction operations*/
{
    public List<List<T>> Lines { get; set; }
    public Matrix()
    {
        Lines = new List<List<T>>();
    }
    public T this[int line, int column]
    {
        get => Lines[line][column];
        set => Lines[line][column] = value;
    }
    public List<T> this[int line]
    {
        get => Lines[line];
    }
    private static T LineMultiplyCol(List<T> l, List<T> c)
    {
        T index = default;
        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
        {
            index += l[i] * c[i]; //Here is the error.
        }
        return index;
    }
    public static Matrix<T> operator *(Matrix<T> m1, Matrix<T> m2)
    {
        //i want to complete this.
    }
}
```

this is my program, i want to expend to Parametric Matrix Operations, and need to do it

[image: this is my program, i want to expend to Parametric Matrix Operations, and need to do it]

Parametric Matrix Operations and etc.

Answer (score 2):

Introduced in .NET 7/C#11 is the new [generic math](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/math). The constraints you are looking for are:

- [IAdditionOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.iadditionoperators-3)
- [IMultiplyOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.imultiplyoperators-3)
- [ISubtractionOperators<TSelf,TOther,TResult>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.isubtractionoperators-3)

Or just use a single constraint: [INumber<TSelf>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.inumber-1)

Comment: thanks lot, do you have any idea to use .Net 7 in VS2019?

Comment: You can download the SDK from https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0 and then change the project target in the project settings. If you have any problems along the way, please ask a new question because it will become too big for the comments, and is out of scope for this question.